# Actionscript 3.0 Listening for a dispatched Custom Event

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I'm having some problems catching a custom event with a listener.

I have a number of objects called keys. Each key, when it is clicked, dispatches a custom event like so:

```
public class Key extends Sprite 
{
    private var letter:String;
    public static const CLICKED:String = "clicked";

    private function keyClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
        this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, keyClicked, false);
        this.mouseEnabled = false;
        dispatchEvent(new Event(CLICKED));
    }
}
```

All of the keys are children of a keyboard object. One of the parents of the keyboard object has an event listener like so:

```
addEventListener(Key.CLICKED, keyboardGuess);
```

which calls

```
public function keyboardGuess(e:Event):void {
        trace("event received");
        var letter:String = e.target.getLetter();
        trace(letter);
    } //there will be other functionality in here when I get it listening
```

However, while I can tell that I am successfully dispatching the event, my listener is never picking it up. I have been going crazy over this for over an hour; can you please help me figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom event's bubbles value should be true, so the object that contains Key could receive the event. And if the bubbles value is false, only the object who dispatch the event could receive the event, like you Key.

About [bubbles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#bubbles).

Try

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(CLICKED, true));
```

Comment: dispatchEvent doesn't default bubbles to true?

Comment: Nope, because I'm dispatching a new Event which defaults to false, which is why I couldn't find it in the API; I was looking under dispatchEvent, not the event constructor. This solved my problem precisely. Thank you so much!